# Add class to checkout button on cart page

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm trying to add classes to the Checkout button by HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter, but the checkout button is not there.

```
 $form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'pull-right';
```

If this is not possible, what is another way to add classes?

[image]

```
function adpomail_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

$form['actions']['continue_shopping'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Continue Shopping'),
  '#weight' => -999,
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['purple'],
  ],
);
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Update cart');
$form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test';}
```

Comment: which form you altered, i have check it and there is `$form['actions']['checkout']` , just if there is no other form alter, altering the same form, and remove the checkout item.

Comment: this is a form presented on /cart page (Drupal Commerce 2)

Comment: I know i have tested it with `$form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'pull-right';`  it works for me thats why i ask you if you haven't any other `hook_form_alter` otherwhere, change the form. in the posted code you have additional `]` .

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. I'm adding a new button, then I modify the existing value, and finally, I want to add the class with no luck.

Comment: i think the form id is  `views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_1` not `views_form_commerce_cart_form_default` try with it .

Comment: The form ID changes from views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_1  to  views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_2 for each order id. I can add and modify the submit button using  views_form_commerce_cart_form_default, but the only problem is with the checkout button. I have managed to add classes via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many way to do this - the one I see suggested most often and that I've used is to modify or create a custom twig template.  To do that;

1. Turn on debug. (see
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)

   2. Find the appropriate template from the suggestions.
   3. Use HOOK_preprocess_hook to either add a class, or add a variable that you pick up in your template.

You can skip #3 if you want to simply override the output of the twig template. However, that means that EVERY form will then have that added class unless a: you can make template very specific, or two build in logic. However, logic is best left to the PHP site of things (your module that you run hook_preprocess_hook in.

The output from debug will help immensely.  For example, I ran it on the login form and it returned this:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'region' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x region--nowrap.html.twig
   * region--content.html.twig
   * region.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/layout/region--nowrap.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/templates/form/form.html.twig' -->

<form class="user-login-form" data-drupal-selector="user-login-form" action="/user/login" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have been using the template suggestion. The only issue with HOOK_preprocess_hook is that it renders each input fields but from the second hand I don't want to rewrite the cart page. However I'm migrating from Drupal 7 to 8, and your answer is very helpful. 
I was surprised why the checkout button is not present inside the hook_form_id ect. functions.

Comment: Have you turned on twig debug per https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates?

If so  and you still don't see "suggestions", you may get further along with https://www.drupal.org/project/twigsuggest

(it digs a little deeper into template suggestions)

Comment: I have tuned the twig debug and get the theme suggestion for submit button (all submit buttons) function for example. I thought it would be good just to write just "one line" to add the class for a single button. I have ended with jquery. I think the TWIG templates are very good if you want to do more then just add css class. Thank you for your help.